# Complete the numerical sequence!

Tags: number-sequence

Complete the following sequence with just one number:

$$4;\ 9;\ 1;\ 6;\ 2;\ ??$$

**Hints**

- It's a real number
- The sequence ends with that number
- There could be literally infinite similar sequences with the same ending number

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Could be:

> Z<sub>ero</sub>

Get it?

> Alphabetically: F<sub>our</sub>, N<sub>ine</sub>, O<sub>ne</sub>,
>  S<sub>ix</sub>, T<sub>wo</sub>, Z<sub>ero</sub>
>  
>  Even the complete alphabetical list of *all integers* ends
>  with Z<sub>ero</sub>

Comment: Great! Exactly!!

Answer (score 5):

The answer is:

> 5

Because:

> 49, 16 and 25 are all perfect squares.
>  And that's where it ends.
>  And there are literally an infinite number of sequences of squares ending in 5.

Comment: or maybe the reason is 4 is a perfect square, so is 9, so is 16 , so is 25. All I mean to say is it might not be 49 according to OP

Comment: Not a bad answer but nope! What if the sequence were been "41, 9, 1, 16, 12,  ?? Your reasoning would fail ^^

Answer (score 2):

> 7

I guess because,

> **4** + *5* = **9**
>  **1** + *5* = **6**
>  **2** + *5* = **7**
>
>  i.e. a consistent difference of 5 between every pair of terms

Comment: Interesting line of thought. To the downvoters, maybe a comment as to why you feel the need to DV this answer? It is as valid as any other correct answer, and if anything, just proves that the original question is too broad!

Comment: Perhaps because the puzzle's assertion that "The sequence ends with that number" is not true of the proposed rule here, for which the sequence could be extended ad infinitum. (@Phylyp)